# multiple radio button on array codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, radio-button

I want to make multiple radio-button on my CodeIgniter webapps, but this value is `null` after I submit my form.

**This is my view on codeigniter apps**

```
<?php $no=0; foreach ($catsub_1_isi as $list2_1a_1a): $no++ ?>

<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('c_QA_roe/simpan_list'); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="WSDetailID[]" value="<?php echo $kode_detail;?>" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="WSHeaderID[]" value="<?php echo $judul->WSHeaderID;?>" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="AppDate[]" value="<?php $tgl=date('Y-m-d-H-i-s'); echo $tgl; ?>" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="InputDate[]" value="<?php $tgl=date('Y-m-d-H-i-s'); echo $tgl; ?>" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="InputUser[]" value="<?php echo $UserName; ?>" class="form-control">                                                     
    <input type="hidden" name="WSListID[]" value="<?php echo $list2_1a_1a->WSListID;?>" class="form-control">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $list2_1a_1a->Subject;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $list2_1a_1a->Standard;?></td>
        <td align="center">
            <div class="radio">
            <input type="text" name="YesNo[<?php echo $list2_1a_1a->WSListID;?>]" value="0">
            <input type="radio" name="YesNo[<?php echo $list2_1a_1a->WSListID;?>]" class="minimal" value="<?php echo $list2_1a_1a->Value;?>" checked>Y
            <input type="text" name="YesNo[<?php echo $list2_1a_1a->WSListID;?>]" value="0">
            <input type="radio" name="YesNo[<?php echo $list2_1a_1a->WSListID;?>]" class="minimal" value="<?php echo $list2_1a_1a->Value;?>">N
            </div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <select name="IsRedudance[]">
                <option value="0">-</option>
                <option value="<?php echo $list2_1a_1a->Value;?>">Yes</option>
            </select>                                               
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <select name="IsUse[]">
                <option value="YES">Yes</option>
                <option value="NO">No</option>
            </select>                                                           
        </td>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

**This is my controller on codeigniter apps**

```
public function simpan_list()
{
    $WSDetailID     = $this->input->post('WSDetailID[]');
    $WSHeaderID     = $this->input->post('WSHeaderID[]'); 
    $WSListID       = $this->input->post('WSListID[]'); 
    $IsYes          = $this->input->post('IsYes[]');
    $IsNo           = $this->input->post('IsNo[]');
    $IsRedudance    = $this->input->post('IsRedudance[]');
    $IsUse          = $this->input->post('IsUse[]');
    $AppDate        = $this->input->post('AppDate[]');
    $InputDate      = $this->input->post('InputDate[]');
    $InputUser      = $this->input->post('InputUser[]');
    $Yes            = $this->input->post('YesNo[]');
    $No             = $this->input->post('YesNo[]');

    $data = array();

    $index = 0; 
    foreach($WSDetailID as $datanis)
    { 
        array_push($data, array(
        'WSDetailID'    =>$datanis,
        'WSHeaderID'    =>$WSHeaderID[$index],
        'WSListID'      =>$WSListID[$index],
        'IsYes'         =>$Yes[$index], 
        'IsNo'          =>$No[$index],          
        'IsRedudance'   =>$IsRedudance[$index],
        'IsUse'         =>$IsUse[$index],
        'AppDate'       =>$AppDate[$index],
        'InputDate'     =>$InputDate[$index],
        'InputUser'     =>$InputUser[$index],
        ));

        $index++;
        var_dump($data['IsYes']);
    }
}
```

on my controller i'am confused about POST data on `$YesNo` especialy variable for multiple radio-button, so I tried to make `post('YesNo[]')` Is this true? but the value is still null

Answer (score 0):

there is no checkbox. but if you want to post the value of checkboxes. you can post this way.

//view

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="active"  placeholder="Active" checked >
```

//controller

```
 'field_name' => ($this->input->post('field_name') == "true") ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: i'am sorry for mistaken title, i mean radio-button not checkbox. so you can help me ?